# Using .sort_by to sort a nested array

Tags: ruby

I have a nested array that I want to sort by a specific object, some advice would be very much appreciated.

In this example I'd like the output to return sorted by the dates that are nested.

```
arr =    [
           [
             {  
               "log"=>[
                 [
                   "2016-09-03T00:00:00-03:00",
                 ],
                 [
                   "2016-09-01T00:00:00-03:00",
                 ],
                 [
                   "2016-09-02T00:00:00-03:00",
                 ]
               ]
             }
           ]
         ]
```

Comment: When you give an example it is helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = [[{ "log"=>....`). That way readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [
        [
          {  
            "log"=>[
               ["2016-09-03T00:00:00-03:00"],
               ["2016-09-01T00:00:00-03:00"],
               ["2016-09-02T00:00:00-03:00"]
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]
```

To return a sorted array and not mutate `arr`:

```
[[{ "log"=>arr[0][0]["log"].sort_by(&:first) }]]
  #=> [[{"log"=>[
  #       ["2016-09-01T00:00:00-03:00"],
  #       ["2016-09-02T00:00:00-03:00"],
  #       ["2016-09-03T00:00:00-03:00"]
  #   ]}]]
```

To sort in place:

```
arr[0][0]["log"] = arr[0][0]["log"].sort_by(&:first)
  #=> [["2016-09-01T00:00:00-03:00"],
  #    ["2016-09-02T00:00:00-03:00"],
  #    ["2016-09-03T00:00:00-03:00"]] 
arr
  #=> [[{"log"=>[
  #       ["2016-09-01T00:00:00-03:00"],
  #       ["2016-09-02T00:00:00-03:00"],
  #       ["2016-09-03T00:00:00-03:00"]
  #   ]}]]
```

Comment: This is only going to work on that single array element. If either of the two outer arrays have multiple elements, it's only going to handle the first one.

Comment: @Jim, yes, that's true, and something I mulled in preparing my answer. The problem is that to deal with a more general case additional specification would be required. Suppose, for example, `arr = [[{ "log"=>[ ["2016-09-03T00:00:00-03:00"], ["2016-09-01T00:00:00-03:00"]] }], [{  "log"=>[ ["2015-08-03T00:00:00-03:00"], ["2015-08-01T00:00:00-03:00"]] }]]`. In this case it's not clear what is wanted.